# Fill color to adjacent cells in Excel add-in in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, plugins, frameworks

I am working on Excel add-in in React js. I have current cell address, for example "B3", know I want to fill color on adjacent cells and itself (left cell, current cell, right cell) with dynamic range. How to achieve this thing? I have searched a lot but nothing helped out.

```
let range = worksheet.getRange(address);
range.format.fill.color = "red";
```

In above code, only current cell is getting red.

Comment: More context is needed to help you on this. Can you share your code.

Comment: @gunwin I don't understand, why more context is needed. I have an address of specific cell say "B2" and I want to fill color this cell and its adjacent cells (A2:B2:C2).

Comment: So the task is, given an excel cell address, find adjacent addresses?

Comment: Yeah! in fact find adjacent range instead adjacent address.